# How to specify the actual x axis values to plot as y axis ticks in R

Tags: plot

How can I change the spacing of tick marks on the y axis, when I have lines with low and lines whit high values? I have tried to 
use this comand:
axis(2, at = seq(1, 7, by = 0.5), las=2)

But it dosn't gives more than values from 2-7 with intervals 0.5. I think it is because the line I have used only has values from 2-7. I have no lines which has values in the whole interval. 
How do I make a plot with tick marks in the whole interval?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ylim` argument to specify the limits of the y-axis like such:

```
x = 1:100
y = seq(2, 7, length.out = 100)

plot(x, y, ylim = c(0,8))
```